# how to set ordered fields in popup contact form with column count 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is js and css:

```
 <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="JS/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

This is body of content:

```
     <h3>External Form</h3>
 <a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myWufooModal">
               Please fill out my form.</a>
 <div class="modal fade" id="myWufooModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content" style="width:700px;">
 <div class="modal-body">
<object type="text/html" data="https://ss88.wufoo.com/forms/rmndx1a0zzpe4m/" style="width:640px;height:730px;"> </object>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

It works fine, but i need name is first field, and second one is email,,

Sample order: 1.name 2.Email(2nd column) 3.company(1st column) 4.Experience(2nd column). like wise.

Can anyone help me, please?..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by using

```
 <ul id="LiForm">
    <li>name</li>
     <li>Email</li>
     <li>company</li>
     <li>Experience</li>

</ul>

$("#LiForm li").sort(function (a, b) { return (a.innerText < b.innerText) ? -1 : ((a.innerText > b.innerText) ? 1 : 0) });
```

Comment: its not normal form, its wufoo form, here there is no <li>, i have just a link for that corresponding link will show a form.